# Windows Server 2016 How to create a local domain version that exists and is public?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, internal-dns

I have this situation. I need to set a domain to a Sharepoint farm and configure it, but the problem is that the domain exists and If I type the domain (let's say it's example.com), I'm being redirected to the real domain.

So practically this is what I wan't to achieve.

- Create a local domain version of example.com in order to access to my sharepoint website.

I have tried this.

- DNS Manager: I create a dns zone for example.com
- Add example.com as host name to website in IIS with port 80
- Changed the url of Sharepoint Web Application to example.com

But it keeps redirecting me to example.com public domain, and it does not create a local version of it in my server.

NOTE: The domain is being used by our customers, so no need to worry about that, we just can't bother the customer to change the domain to point another server because the domain is used in production websites, and we just wan't to test things with domain. That is the reason why customer can't point his domain to another server.

Comment: Disconnect from the Internet.

Comment: sorry but I can't do that, the server has other websites in Sharepoint that can't be shut down.

Comment: You'll have to use a different name, then.

Comment: Would you mind if I used your domain name for my internal sites?

Comment: Did you run nslookup from the client ? Is the client part of AD domain ? IS the DNS ad integrated ?

Comment: the domain is being used in production, it's already purchased by our customer, so no need to worry about that, but we just can't change the dns of the domain in production to point another website, because we still need to finish somo configurations. Yes the client is part of the AD domain

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised how no one answered it, but I found the solution which is pretty easy.

Just go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and edit the hosts file

I just added the domain like this:

ipaddress example.com